# Keep track of only 2 active UITextFields

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I've a series of 5 security questions (question: `UILabel`, answer: `UITextField`).
I'm trying to keep the user's answer to only 2 questions.
When user answer 2 questions I'm trying to disable the rest of the `UITextField`.
I can to color it to lightGray but when user tap 3rd `UITextField` nothing's happen.

Another thing,
I'm trying to keep the text inside the `UITextField` but when user hit backward or forward questions disappear, somehow `viewDidLoad` always get called when it should called only once.

I was trying to set `NO` to `UITextFields` `enabled` & `userInteractionEnabled` properties and it doesn't work.

1. How to keep and maintain only 2 fields of answers so user cannot answer more then 2?
2. How to maintain the user input inside the fields?

My entire class, I'll glad for help:

```
#define kUN_CHECKED     0
#define kCHECKED        1

@interface QuestionsAnswersPage () {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults;
    NSMutableDictionary *_QnA;
}
@end

@implementation QuestionsAnswersPage

- (void)setupGUI
{
    NSString *culture = MFLocalizedString(@"culture", nil);

    if ([culture isEqualToString:@"he-IL"] || [culture isEqualToString:@"ar-EG"]) {
        for (UIView *view in self.contentView.subviews) {
            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
                [(UILabel *)view setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
            }
            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
                [(UITextField *)view setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
            }
            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]) {
                [(UITextView *)view setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
                [(UILabel *)view setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
            }
            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
                [(UITextField *)view setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
            }
            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]) {
                [(UITextView *)view setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)setupLayout
{
    [self setupIOS7Layout];
    [self setupNaviBarWithTitle:MFLocalizedString(@"sequrity_questions", nil)];
}

- (void)setupIOS7Layout
{
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;
    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars=NO;
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=NO;
}

- (void)setupNaviBarWithTitle:(NSString *)title
{
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:OrangeOfficialColor];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    self.navigationItem.title = title;

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:MFLocalizedString(@"continue_text", nil)
                                                                              style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                             target:self
                                                                             action:@selector(btnDone:)];
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self)
    {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    self.textViewDescription.text = MFLocalizedString(@"sequrity_questions_message", nil);

    [self setupLayout];

    _QnA = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setupGUI) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

    self.imageBG.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"splash.png"];
    if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568) {
        self.imageBG.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"splash-568h.png"];
    }

//    self.textAnswer1.delegate = self;
//    self.textAnswer2.delegate = self;
//    self.textAnswer3.delegate = self;
//    self.textAnswer4.delegate = self;
//    self.textAnswer5.delegate = self;

//    self.textAnswer1.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
//    self.textAnswer2.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
//    self.textAnswer3.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
//    self.textAnswer4.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
//    self.textAnswer5.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
//    
//    self.labelQuestion1.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
//    self.labelQuestion2.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
//    self.labelQuestion3.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
//    self.labelQuestion4.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
//    self.labelQuestion5.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

    self.textAnswer1.placeholder = MFLocalizedString(@"answer_only_in_numbers", nil);
    self.textAnswer2.placeholder = MFLocalizedString(@"answer_only_in_numbers", nil);
    self.textAnswer3.placeholder = MFLocalizedString(@"answer_only_in_numbers", nil);
    self.textAnswer4.placeholder = MFLocalizedString(@"answer_only_in_numbers", nil);
    self.textAnswer5.placeholder = MFLocalizedString(@"answer_only_in_numbers", nil);
    /*
    BOOL didGetQuestion = [defaults boolForKey:@"didGetQuestion"];

    if (didGetQuestion) {
        [self handleQuestions];
    }
    else {
        [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"didGetQuestion"];
        [defaults synchronize];

        [SVProgressHUD show];

        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [appDelegate startParsingGetQuestions];
            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

            [self handleQuestions];
        });
    }
     */
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self saveAskForPasswordState:NO];

    BOOL didGetQuestion = [defaults boolForKey:@"didGetQuestion"];

    if (didGetQuestion) {
        [self handleQuestions];
    }
    else {
        [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"didGetQuestion"];
        [defaults synchronize];

        [SVProgressHUD show];

        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [appDelegate startParsingGetQuestions];
            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

            [self handleQuestions];
        });
    }
}

- (void)handleQuestions
{
    self.labelQuestion1.text = [defaults objectForKey:@"question_number_1"];
    self.labelQuestion2.text = [defaults objectForKey:@"question_number_2"];
    self.labelQuestion3.text = [defaults objectForKey:@"question_number_3"];
    self.labelQuestion4.text = [defaults objectForKey:@"question_number_4"];
    self.labelQuestion5.text = [defaults objectForKey:@"question_number_5"];

    NSString *question1 = [defaults objectForKey:@"user_question_id_1"];
    NSString *question2 = [defaults objectForKey:@"user_question_id_2"];
    NSString *answer1 =   [defaults objectForKey:@"user_answer_id_1"];
    NSString *answer2 =   [defaults objectForKey:@" user_answer_id_2"];

    if (answer1.length == 0 || answer2.length == 0) {
        NSLog(@"User didn't fill 2 questions.");
    }
    else {
        for (UIView *view in self.contentView.subviews) {
            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
                UITextField *field = (UITextField *)view;

                if (field.tag == question1.integerValue) {
                    field.text = answer1;
                }
                else if (field.tag == question2.integerValue) {
                    field.text = answer2;
                }
                else {
                    field.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
                    field.enabled = NO;

                    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self.contentView viewWithTag:field.tag+5];
                    label.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(textFieldDidChange:)
                                                 name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
                                                  object:nil];
}

- (void)dismissKeyboard
{
    [self.textAnswer1 resignFirstResponder];
    [self.textAnswer2 resignFirstResponder];
    [self.textAnswer3 resignFirstResponder];
    [self.textAnswer4 resignFirstResponder];
    [self.textAnswer5 resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)saveAskForPasswordState:(BOOL)isChecked
{
    if (isChecked)
    {
        [defaults setObject:@"true" forKey:@"askForPassword"];
    }
    else
    {
        [defaults setObject:@"false" forKey:@"askForPassword"];
    }
    [defaults synchronize];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

- (IBAction)btnDone:(id)sender
{
    NSUInteger qCounter = 0;

    for (UIView *view in self.contentView.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            UITextField *field = (UITextField *)view;

            if (field.text.length > 0) {
                qCounter++;

                [defaults setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)field.tag]
                             forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"user_question_id_%lu", (unsigned long)qCounter]];

                [defaults setObject:field.text
                             forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"user_answer_id_%lu", (unsigned long)qCounter]];

                [defaults synchronize];
            }
        }
    }

    if (qCounter == 2) {
        EmergencyPickContacts *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:
                                             NSStringFromClass([EmergencyPickContacts class])];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
//        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"QuestionsToEmergencySegue" sender:self];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"User didn't fill 2 questions.");
    }
}

- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}

- (BOOL)willResign
{
    NSUInteger counter = 0;

    for (UIViewController *view in self.contentView.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            UITextField *field = (UITextField *)view;

            if (field.text.length > 0) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }

    return counter == 2;
}

#pragma mark - UITextFieldDelegate Methods

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSUInteger counter = 0;

    // Count how many questions have answers
    for (UIView *view in self.contentView.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            UITextField *field = (UITextField *)view;

            if (field.text.length > 0) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }

    if (textField.text.length > 0 && counter == 2) {
        for (UIView *view in self.contentView.subviews) {
            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
                UITextField *field = (UITextField *)view;

                if (field.text.length == 0) {
                    field.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
                    field.enabled = NO;

                    [self changeQuestionTextColorWithID:field.tag willBlock:YES];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        for (UIView *view in self.contentView.subviews) {
            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
                UITextField *field = (UITextField *)view;
                field.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                field.enabled = YES;

                [self changeQuestionTextColorWithID:field.tag willBlock:NO];
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)changeQuestionTextColorWithID:(NSUInteger)answerTag willBlock:(BOOL)block
{
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self.contentView viewWithTag:answerTag+5];
    label.textColor = block ? [UIColor lightGrayColor] : [UIColor darkGrayColor];
}

- (void)textFieldDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)notification.object;

    if (textField.text.length == 0) {
        for (UIView *view in self.contentView.subviews) {
            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
                UITextField *field = (UITextField *)view;
                field.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                field.enabled = YES;

                UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self.contentView viewWithTag:field.tag+5];
                label.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
            }
        }
    }
}

- (NSUInteger)numberOfActiveTextFields
{
    NSUInteger counter = 0;

    for (UIView *view in self.contentView.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            if ([(UITextField*)view text].length > 0) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    return counter;
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSCharacterSet *nonNumberSet = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];
    return ([string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:nonNumberSet].length > 0) || [string isEqualToString:@""];
}

@end
```

Comment: Incorrect design. Use two picker views for the question, text fields for answers. No need to disable anything, no need to explicitly tell the user you can only set two security questions. Also, no one here will have the time to go through all of your class. Please post only relevant code.

Comment: The design is dictated to me although I think like you, the design is bad.

Comment: Poor you… best of luck.

Comment: Thanks, any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Well… if you could narrow down the hunk of code you posted to a more manageable amount, perhaps I could have a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Introduction**

Apple provides a [UITextFieldDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) protocol for you to use. This protocol has useful methods that help you gain information about the state of your UITextField(s), including whether or not the user has begun editing them (which might be useful to you).

**Implementing this protocol**

There are a few steps that are necessary to implement the UITextFieldDelegate protocol in Objective-C. Below, a high-level overview is provided. This answer will go through the following steps in greater detail.

1. Adding UITextFieldDelegate to your UIViewController
2. Setting the delegate of your UITextFields as your UIViewController
3. Implementing the appropriate methods

**Adding UITextFieldDelegate to your UIViewController**

This step is pretty simple. Go ahead and open up your header file (.h file) for your view controller) (e.g. QuestionsAnswersPage.h).

You should see something like:

```
@interface QuestionsAnswersPage : UIViewController
    // some of your code...
@end
```

After `UIViewController`, add `<UITextFieldDelegate>`. Now it will look like:

```
@interface QuestionsAnswersPage : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
    // some of your code...
@end
```

**Setting the delegate of your UITextFields as your UIViewController**

There are two ways to do this. The first is through the storyboard, and the second is programmatic. I'll give you the programmatic version.

Locate your `viewDidLoad:` method in your implementation file (.m file) (e.g. QuestionsAnswersPage.m). In this method, add the following lines of code.

```
yourTextField1.delegate = self;
yourTextField2.delegate = self;
yourTextField3.delegate = self;
// ... similarly for other text fields ...
```

Remember to replace the text field names in the lines of code above.

**Implementing the appropriate methods**

At this point, your delegate is ready for method implementation. Here is one method that would be particularly useful to you. Just add this method in your implementation (.m file) and fill in its body with your implementation. Keep in mind that you may need to have global variables that act as counters, or references in order to facilitate what you specifically are trying to do..

```
/** This method lets you know that a particular text field has finished edits. 
 */ 
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    /* It would be a good idea here to check if the following things
     * (1) Is the UITextField blank? (check whether it has stuff in it or not)
     * (2) If the UITextField is not blank, then have you reached the maximum 
     *     number of filled-in text fields? if so, disable all the empty ones.
     * (3) If the UITextField is blank, then you might have to re-enable user
     *     user interaction with the other UITextFields, if this UITextField was
     *     filled in before
     */
}
```

Another good method that you might find a need for is:

```
/** This method lets you know that a particular text field is now being edited. 
 */ 
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    // Your code here...
}
```

**Honing your implementation**

At this point you are all set up. I'd recommend having a counter that checks how many UITextFields already have text in them, and references to keep track of those; this way it's easy to keep track of changes in your UITextFields. Good luck, and again, you can find out more about the UITextFieldDelegate [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html).

Comment: please don't call Views Pages. this isn't website programming

Comment: While agree with you, @vikingosegundo, the question asked has "QuestionsAnswersPage" as one of the view controllers, so I used that in the example.

Comment: oh, sorry. OP was tldr;